# How can i use generated HTML (using JS) with another JS script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am really new to JS, and i am making an excersise that is creating a dynamic menu, it is pretty simple, actually is this exact menu:

http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/vertical-accordion-menu-using-jquery-css3

thing is, if i use this exact code everything works just fine, but if i take out the `<div id="accordian">` part and replace it with a JS that generates it (to generate dynamic menus in the future) it stops working, everything shows (even the sub-menus) but can't slide them back up. I have never done anything like this before, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Can you sure your code? It's really difficult to tell what you're doing wrong without knowing what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/latuxi/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

<sup>(please don't use "accordi**A**n"... it's simply uff nghhh :)</sup>
So the **accordiOn**  in the demo uses the ID `accordion` like in

```
<div id="accordion">
```

Simply don't use ID! - **Use classes!**

```
<div class="accordion"><!-- menu here bla bla --></div>
```

and than in jQuery:

```
/*jQuery time*/
$(document).ready(function(){

    // $(".accordion h3").click(function(){ NO! use dynamic click delegation
    $(document).on("click", ".accordion h3", function(){
        //slide up all the link lists
        // $("#accordian ul ul").slideUp(); Wrong. Reference to this!
        $(this).closest(".accordion").find("ul ul").slideUp();
        //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
        if(!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
        }
    });

});
```

The above code will work also for dynamically generated accordions cause we used the `.on()` method that will delegate the click event to existing, but also to future elements.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, however i tried this on my code but did not work, idk if it is the way i generate de HTML, i have been watching it and seems to work fine.

It generate the list of elements as it is supossed to , however it keeps showing all the elements instead of waiting for the click to show them or hide them

Comment: @RodolfoJoséMiquilarena have you seen my jsBin example? Have you renamed all the `#accordian` into `.accordion` (CLASS!!) inside the CSS? Have you fixed the typo `accordian > accordion` ? So, as you can see the code works perfectly fine.